# Can I use in and advenire together?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice, compound-verb, prefix

Is it grammatical to combine *in* and *advenire* to say, for example, *in Finniam advenit*?
This sounds otherwise fine to me, but I'm slightly worried about mixing the prepositions *in* and *ad* so I want to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is an attested usage. Lewis and Short should be your first place to check for such information. For [advenio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dadvenio) they specifically give the list of constructions "absol., with ad, in, or acc.", and cite several examples with *in*. Here's an example from Cicero, *Philippic* 11.30:

> quamcumque in provinciam eius belli gerendi causa advenerit

"in whatever province he arrives for the purpose of waging that war"